# Removing whitespace after already stripping lines?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am having a problem with removing all the whitespace from a Fasta file, here is the program I have so far:

```
import re
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip(' \n\r')
        if line.startswith(">"):
            seqid = re.search('Segment:[(0-9)]',line).group()
            seqID.append(seqid)
        else:
            numSeq = len(line)
```

This is what the test file looks like (I only used the first couple just to show the seqId):

```
>gb:CY170782|Organism:Influenza A virus A/Santa Clara/YGA_03044/2013|Segment:1|Subtype:H3N2|Host:Human
ATTATATTCAGTATGGAAAGAATAAAAGAACTACGGAATCTGATGTCGCAGTCTCGCACTCGCGAGATAC
TGACAAAAACCACAGTGGACCATATGGCCATAATTAAGAAGTACACATCGGGGAGACAGGAAAAGAACCC
GTCACTTAGGATGAAATGGATGATGGCAATGAAATATCCAATCACTGCTGACAAAAGGGTAACAGAAATG

>gb:CY171006|Organism:Influenza A virus A/Santa Clara/YGA_03075/2013|Segment:1|Subtype:H3N2|Host:Human
ATTATATTCAGTATGGAAAGAATAAAAGAATTACGGAATCTGATGTCGCAATCTCGCACTCGCGAGATAC
TGACAAAAACCACAGTGGACCATATGGCCATAATTAAGAAGTACACATCGGGGAGACAGGAAAAGAACCC
GTCACTTAGGATGAAATGGATGATGGCAATGAAATACCCAATCACTGCTGACAAAAGAATAACAGAAATG
```

When I go to print it out, it prints out like this:

```
ATTATATTCAGTATGGAAAGAATAAAAGAACTACGGAATCTGATGTCGCAGTCTCGCACTCGCGAGATAC 70
TGACAAAAACCACAGTGGACCATATGGCCATAATTAAGAAGTACACATCGGGGAGACAGGAAAAGAACCC 70
GTCACTTAGGATGAAATGGATGATGGCAATGAAATATCCAATCACTGCTGACAAAAGGGTAACAGAAATG 70
 0
ATTATATTCAGTATGGAAAGAATAAAAGAATTACGGAATCTGATGTCGCAATCTCGCACTCGCGAGATAC 70
TGACAAAAACCACAGTGGACCATATGGCCATAATTAAGAAGTACACATCGGGGAGACAGGAAAAGAACCC 70
GTCACTTAGGATGAAATGGATGATGGCAATGAAATACCCAATCACTGCTGACAAAAGAATAACAGAAATG 70
 0
ATTATATTCAGTATGGAAAGAATAAAAGAACTACGGAATCTGATGTCGCAGTCTCGCACTCGCGAGATAC 70
TGACAAAAACCACAGTGGACCATATGGCCATAATTAAGAAGTACACATCGGGGAGACAGGAAAAGAACCC 70
GTCACTTAGGATGAAATGGATGATGGCAATGAAATATCCAATCACTGCTGACAAAAGGGTAACAGAAATG 70
 0
```

How do I get it to join the lines and remove the lines with 0 nucleotides? Sorry for poor wording due to the lack of sleep. If you have questions about my question feel free to ask.

Here is the full program:

```
from __future__ import division
import re
f = open('fastatest.fasta','r')
numGC = 0;
allGC = []; #array that contains all the GC%'s
sequences = []; #The array that contains all the sequences
seqID = []; #The array that contains all seqIds
seqLen = [];
numSeq = 0
GCPercent = 0
#Concatinating the FASTA file
for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip(' \n\r')
    if line.startswith(">"):
        seqid = re.search('Segment:[(0-9)]',line).group()
        seqID.append(seqid)
    else: #Find the Length and GC%
        numSeq = len(line)
        #print seqid, numSeq
        GCPercent = (( line.count('G') + line.count('C') ) / (numSeq)*100)
        allGC.append(GCPercent);
        sequences.append(line)
        seqLen.append(numSeq)
        print "%s\t%d\t%.2f" % (seqid,numSeq,GCPercent)
```

And the output I am receiving:

```
Segment:1   70  40.00
Segment:1   70  44.29
Segment:1   70  38.57
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blah", line 20, in <module>
    GCPercent = (( line.count('G') + line.count('C') ) / (numSeq)*100)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: Example of the input file would be useful.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what the input file looks like?

Comment: I run your example code with example input file and your output you are getting is far from you have listed. Is it the complete code snippet you provided?

Comment: No, its not the full code, I am just trying to figure out how to remove the empty lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the file has an empty line after each sequence (also after the last sequence!), this should work:

```
if line.startswith(">"):
    seqid = re.search('Segment:[(0-9)]',line).group()
    seqID.append(seqid)
    sequence = ""
elif len(line.strip()): 
    sequence += line.strip()  # three lines will make a sequence
else: #Find the Length and GC%
    numSeq = len(sequence)
    #print seqid, numSeq
    GCPercent = (( sequence.count('G') + sequence.count('C') ) / (numSeq)*100)
    allGC.append(GCPercent);
    sequences.append(sequence)
    seqLen.append(numSeq)
    print "%s\t%d\t%.2f" % (seqid,numSeq,GCPercent)
```

I just added three lines and replaced `line` with `sequence` on four locations. Looks like a minimal change solution, I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 2):

try using Biopython

```
from Bio import SeqIO
for record in SeqIO.parse("fasta.fas","fasta"):
     print record.id
     print record.seq
```

this should remove all new line etc...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a conditional append works?

```
if not seqid.strip.startswith('0'):
    seqID.append(seqid)
```

If not it would help to see how `seqid` looks like.

Comment: After looking at the data example and output, it seems that this answer doesn't make sense. Below a new answer based on the example.

Answer (score 0):

You could jump straight to the next iteration of the loop when the length of the line is 0:

```
numSeq = len(line)  # from your code for reference
if not numSeq:
    continue
```

Comment: That solves the zero division problem. Would  you happen to know how to make it so it will wrap the segment together instead of stopping after 70 nucleotides?

Comment: I think you could use `''.join(sequences)`

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore empty lines by checking for them:

```
from __future__ import division
import re

numGC = 0;
allGC = []; #array that contains all the GC%'s
sequences = []; #The array that contains all the sequences
seqID = []; #The array that contains all seqIds
seqLen = [];
numSeq = 0
GCPercent = 0

with open('fastatest.fasta', 'r') as f:
    #Concatinating the FASTA file
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip(' \n\r')
        if line:  # non-empty line?
            if line.startswith(">"):
                seqid = re.search('Segment:[(0-9)]',line).group()
                seqID.append(seqid)
            else: #Find the Length and GC%
                numSeq = len(line)
                #print seqid, numSeq
                GCPercent = ((line.count('G') + line.count('C')) /
                             (numSeq)*100)
                allGC.append(GCPercent);
                sequences.append(line)
                seqLen.append(numSeq)
                print "%s\t%d\t%.2f" % (seqid,numSeq,GCPercent)
```

Output:

```
Segment:1   70  40.00
Segment:1   70  44.29
Segment:1   70  38.57
Segment:1   70  37.14
Segment:1   70  44.29
Segment:1   70  37.14
```